# Send a template partial as a message on phoenix channels

Tags: phoenix-framework, phoenix-channels

Is this a bad idea to send a partial template using channels?

The other option is to send a JSON and have a duplicate template on javascript and eex.

I’m asking this because I don’t know the channels internals and it may have a message size limit or some other drawbacks.

Here is how I would send it on controller after saving the post:

```elixir
case Repo.insert(post) do
  {:ok, post} ->
    Endpoint.broadcast!("users:global", "new_post",
      %{partial: Phoenix.View.render_to_string(YourApp.SharedView, "post.html", post: post)})
end
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: I don't remember if this is exactly the right syntax, but this is the way Chris McCord recommended.